# Resetting a user's password using Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to write a web portal that users can use to reset their own Azure AD password.  Because of the requirements of my client, the **Azure AD SSPR is not an option**.

To achieve this I'm using Microsoft Graph.  According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#ResetUserPassword), it is possible to reset a users password using Microsoft Graph if you have `User.ReadWrite.All` or `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permissions.

Then the [permissions documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#directory-permissions), the remarks it states that even if you have the `Directory.ReadWrite.All` permissions you won't be able to reset a users password.

I've done a test to see if this will work but I get an `HTTP 403 Forbidden` response.

The code I'm using is:

```
string ResourceUrl = "https://graph.windows.net/";
string AuthorityUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/companyxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize/";

//Create a user password cradentials.
var credential = new Microsoft.IdentityModel
    .Clients
    .ActiveDirectory
    .UserPasswordCredential("username@xxxx.com", "passwordxxx");

// Authenticate using created credentials
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorityUrl);

var authenticationResult = authenticationContext
    .AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, "xxxxxxxx-3017-4833-9923-30d05726b32f", credential)
    .Result;

string jwtToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
var cred = new Microsoft.Rest
    .TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
queryString["api-version"] = "1.6";
client.DefaultRequestHeaders
    .Accept
    .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwtToken);

var uri = "https://graph.windows.net/xxxxxxxx-18fe-xxxx-bb90-d62195600495/users/xxxxxxxx-aa58-4329-xxxx-b39af07325ee?" + queryString;

//var content = new StringContent("{\"passwordProfile\": {\"password\": \"Test123456\", \"forceChangePasswordNextLogin\": true }}");
var response = client.PatchAsync(new Uri(uri), content, jwtToken);
```

The `PatchAsync` method is an extension method as below:

```
public static class HttpClientExtensions
{
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchAsync(this HttpClient client,
        Uri requestUri, HttpContent iContent, string jwtToken)
    {
        var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri)
        {
            Content = iContent,
        };
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType =
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        request.Headers.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwtToken);

        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        try
        {
            response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.ToString());
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Could someone please clarify if this is possible using the **credentials grant flow** with a username and password for authentication.  If so how do I achieve this?

Comment: Have you checked if the JWT contains the necessary scope? You can use a tool like https://jwt.ms for decoding the token.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up Microsoft Graph and Azure AD Graph API. These are two different APIs and calls to one are not interchangeable with the other.

You are correct in that you need to use the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` scope for this activity. This scope allows the API to do anything to the AAD that the signed in user would be able to do themselves (i.e. change their own password).

Once you have a valid `access_token` for the user with `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission, you can update the user's [`passwordProfile`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/passwordprofile):

```http
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
Content-type: application/json

{
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "password-value"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok but the idea is that I create a user with the correct permissions on Azure AD and then use that user to reset a guest user's password.  How would I achieve this using Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: you **can't** change a password for **guest** user in Azure AD. This is the idea of guest accounts - they manage their own passwords (in ideal scenario these already managed by own IT department) and you only manage their access to business critical applications.