# Microsoft-Graph - As an Azure AD Admin how you can get a valid access_token for another user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

If I understood the response from user `@MarcLaFleur` here: [Resetting a user's password using Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866745/1232087), if you are an `Azure AD admin` and want to reset a password of another user using `Microsoft Graph API` then you need to have a valid `access_token` for the user with `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission, and then you can update the user's passwordProfile.

**Question**: Using Microsoft Graph, as an Azure AD Admin, how can we get `access_token` for another user?

**Authentication Page of my App Registration**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are an `Azure AD admin` and want to reset the password of another user using Microsoft Graph API, you just need to get the token for the admin account itself, not the user you want to change.

In this case, you could use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).

1.In your AD App, add the permissions like below -> click `Grant admin consent for xxx` button.

[image]

2.Login your admin account with the url below in the browser.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<client-id>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

3.Use the code to get the token.

[image]

4.Use the token to change the password of a normal user.

[image]

---

You could also use the [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request), use [Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#AuthCodeProvider).

Something like below:

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret) // or .WithCertificate(certificate)
    .Build();

AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scopes);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var user = new User
            {
                PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                {
                    ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
                    Password = password,
                }
            };

await graphClient.Users[userId]
                   .Request()
                   .UpdateAsync(user);
```

Comment: I tried the URL from your `step 2` above by first entering the valid tenant id and client id for my registered app. And for Redirect URI my app is using `http://localhost`, so in your URL I used `http://localhost`. But I get the error message `AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: 'my client id here'..` I even tried [Prefer-127001-over-localhost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#prefer-127001-over-localhost) but still the same error.

Comment: @nam Could you show the screenshot of `Authentication` page of your App registration?

Comment: At the end of my post, I just have added the screenshot your requested. Also, I am using `Microsoft Graph SDK and Authorization code provider`. In your SDK example where are you using `access_token`?

Comment: @nam 1.I suppose your app is not a public client, so you need to add a `Web` type redirect url, click `Add a platform` -> `Web` -> input `http://localhost`, then try step2 again. 2.The sdk `AuthorizationCodeProvider` automatically uses the auth code flow, no need to use access_token manually.

Comment: I am using SDK, and your second method worked for me (thank you). Instead of `AuthorizationCodeProvider` I am using `InteractiveAuthenticationProvider`, is that ok?

Comment: @nam Yes, it’s ok.